# I believe the following are isomorphic to $S_4$, how do I check?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-isomorphism, isometry

I am told that the (orientation preserving) isometries of the cube, taken as a group, are isomorphic to $S_4$. I don't understand anything "4" about the cube. At least, nothing "4" about it was obvious. So, instead of looking for "4", I took a cube and drew a picture with this labeling:
[image]

And I decided that the three rotations are probably going to generate what I want, so I codified them (in parity with this picture) by letting:

$r_1=(1 \ 3 \ 6 \ 4)$
$r_2=(1 \ 2 \ 6 \ 5)$
$r_3=(2 \ 4 \ 5 \ 3)$

Am I heading down a bad alley? Please no exhaustive answers, I am just looking for helpful hints (including "change your course of action, this won't work")

thank you!

Comment: One way to see "4": there are 4 long diagonals to a cube!

Comment: I guess I should have looked harder. Thanks! I'll see what I can do.

Comment: You see nothing 4 about the cube?  Not 4 sides on each face?

Comment: I got caught up in the 6 faces, 8 corners, and 12 edges

Comment: From your 3 cycles of 4, you can certainly generate the entire group of $S_4.$

Comment: Have a look here: http://garsia.math.yorku.ca/~zabrocki/math4160w03/cubesyms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group $G$ of $24$ rotations acts on the set $D$ of $4$ diagonals of the cube.  It can be shown that the corresponding group homomorphism from $G$ into $Sym(D)$ is injective.  Hence, the image is $Sym(D) \cong S_4$.

Comment: thanks. This problem boiled down to this conjecture: If a rotation fixes at least three of the cube diagonals, then it is actually the identity map. In such a case, the rotation actually fixes all four diagonals.

I proved this by taking the at least 3 fixed diagonals and choosing an orthoganal basis from inside of them. What choices does the rotation have for these? Representing elements as pairs of coefficients of the basis vectors quickly shows that any choice which sends a vector to its opposite is actually a reflection. Not allowed! Thanks for the tip.